# Restore mysql data Digital Ocean

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

I try to restore data from binlog.
I'm using MySQL from Digital Ocean managed database
https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases-mysql

When I run `SHOW BINARY LOGS;` it show only 3 row, size is small with some text. I tried to google but not found any solution.

[image]